# Aggregate function for arranging a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

I have following dataframe,

```
>>> data = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['CTA15', 'CTA15', 'AC007', 'AC007', 'AC007'], 
'ID': [22, 22, 2, 2, 2], 
'Sample':['PE12', 'PL14', 'AE29', 'AE04', 'PE03'], 
'count_col' : [2, 2, 3, 3, 3]})

>>> data
   ID   Name Sample  count_col
0  22  CTA15   PE12          2
1  22  CTA15   PL14          2
2   2  AC007   AE29          3
3   2  AC007   AE04          3
4   2  AC007   PE03          3
```

I need to rearrange my data frame as following,

```
 Name       Sample      count_col
    CTA15       PE12          2
                PL14        
    AC007       AE10          3
                AE29    
                PE03
```

What I tried is,

```
pd.pivot_table(All_variants_REL,index=["Name",'Sample'],
               values=['Count'],aggfunc={'Name':np.size})
```

But it not showing accurate count in count column
Any helps would be great..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) + [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) by boolean mask created by [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

*Notice: I add cast to `str`, because else get mixed values in column `count` (strings with ints) and some pandas function can be broken.*

*Notice1 - Solution works, if values in `Name` column are sorted.*

```
cols = ['Name','count']
df[cols] = df[cols].astype(str).mask(df.duplicated(['Name']), '')
print (df)
    Name  ID Sample count
0  CTA15  22   PE12     2
1         22   PL14      
2  AC007   2   AE29     3
3          2   AE04      
4          2   PE03
```

If need `NaNs` simply omit `,` - but last column values are convert to `float` (because `NaN` is float)

```
cols = ['Name','count']
df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df.duplicated(['Name']))
print (df)
    Name  ID Sample  count
0  CTA15  22   PE12    2.0
1    NaN  22   PL14    NaN
2  AC007   2   AE29    3.0
3    NaN   2   AE04    NaN
4    NaN   2   PE03    NaN
```

For `lists` is possible use:

```
cols = ['Name','count', 'ID']
df = df.groupby(cols)['Sample'].apply(list).reset_index()
print (df)
    Name  count  ID              Sample
0  AC007      3   2  [AE29, AE04, PE03]
1  CTA15      2  22        [PE12, PL14]
```

Comment: Thank you for a solution what If I have many more columns in data frame. And I need those columns to be shown as well ?

Comment: Hmmm, it depends what do you need. Obviously is not problem if data are duplicated in columns. Another possible solution is create lists with data in `Sample` column, but then use some pandas function is harder.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply set a multi index? Doing so will translate to having all columns show if you have many more columns than in the example `DataFrame`.

```
>>> data = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['CTA15', 'CTA15', 'AC007', 'AC007', 'AC007'], 
'ID': [22, 22, 2, 2, 2], 
'Sample':['PE12', 'PL14', 'AE29', 'AE04', 'PE03'], 
'count_col' : [2, 2, 3, 3, 3]})
```

(Side note: I wouldn't recommend having a column with the name `count` as it is a `DataFrame` method and will cause issues down the road. For example, `data.count` does not return a `Series` as we might expect.)

```
>>> data
   ID   Name Sample  count_col
0  22  CTA15   PE12          2
1  22  CTA15   PL14          2
2   2  AC007   AE29          3
3   2  AC007   AE04          3
4   2  AC007   PE03          3
```

Set the multi index, which will serve as solution for an arbitrarily large `DataFrame`.

```
>>> data.set_index(['Name', 'Sample'])
              ID  count_col
Name  Sample               
CTA15 PE12    22          2
      PL14    22          2
AC007 AE29     2          3
      AE04     2          3
      PE03     2          3
```